# Magento reload issue ipad category page when clicking back button product page

Tags: image, performance, magento

We are having a problem at our shop in the following situation:

You are at the category page and click to a product page. After you click at the back button in your browser the category page does not reload. At the category page we have a mouse over for the images.

By this the image at the category page disappear at a iPad and iphone. This is only with one of our templates and by an other it is just working fine.

Can someone let me know if there is a controller or something else that does this.

Kind regards,

Coen Walstra

Comment: Do you have this issue in safari (desktop) or chrome?